# Two Node Apps, One Nginx Server

Tags: nginx

I'm very new to using Nginx, but it doesn't seem that complicated. I have two node apps (using forever), one running on port 2368 (domainA) and the other on 2367 (sub.domainB).

domainA works as expected. But sub.domainB reports a 502 error.

Here are my configuration files:

Server is running Ubuntu 15.04

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`etc/nginx/sites-available/domainA.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domainA.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_ip:2368;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

`etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.domainB.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name sub.domainB.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_ip:2367;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to start the service that's supposed to listen on port 2367.

Comment: It is, but pointed at the wrong IP. Your comment pointed me in the right direction however. Will update with my own answer momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration above was correct, however, in my application I was pointing to 127.0.0.1 in the production environment for the node app located at sub.domainB.com. Changing this to the ip address of the machine (like the other node app) fixed the issue.